# Database queries as application healthchecks - management tool

Tags: database, monitoring, nagios, health-monitoring, sensu

Hey there fellow Stackoverflowers,

In our company we have several application stacks running on different types of databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL, Azure SQL,..). For monitoring purposes we use some scripted queries on the databases of all these application stacks, with Nagios reporting back the results in an email.

Now, since our support team would also like easy access to these queries in order to manually run them or modify them, we were considering building an application specifically designed to be able to store, run and modify queries that can be executed on any of the above listed database types and offering both a user-friendly webinterface and a REST API with JSON output for our new reporting stack based on SENSU, to be deployed in a few months.

My personal belief is that a tool like this must already be out there, since the use case for it is so generic. However, googling did not yield any results even closely resembling what I am looking for.

So my question to you is: Do you know of such a tool? If you had to build it yourself: what would your approach be? We're mostly a Java/C++ team, but are open to all options.

Answer (score 0):

Some or may be all of this stuff can be done by an existing API called NAGIRA. Look it up on Google. This will definitely give you all the results in JSON format. Also i think it would allow you to run checks manually. So you can may be build a little front end and call this API to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A little late of a reply, but check out http://cloudmonix.com -- it offers ability to create metrics based on custom SQL queries, supports SQL Azure, SQL Server, MySQL, and Oracle.  Also integrates with Nagios (and Zabbix)